# Location within a building using the wifi hotspot

Tags: android, location, android-wifi

I am trying to build an android application which changes the alert profile of the phone according to the location. I am using Google maps to get the location of the user. But this gives me the location only up to the granularity of a building.
For example, Google map might tell that I am in my office building, but not whether I am in a meeting room or the pantry. And I might want different profiles for the two places.
Assuming the building has a separate wireless router in each room, I plan to use the wifi hot spot to get the precise location.

Will this be possible? Is there a service/app already existing for this?
Any other ideas to achieve this are also welcome.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a technology that can pinpoint an iPhone's *exact* location (to the feet/couple feet, indoors)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058369/is-there-a-technology-that-can-pinpoint-an-iphones-exact-location-to-the-fee)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's an active [research topic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indoor_positioning_system) that has no real solution yet. You might be able to get information about signal strength of close hotspots (don't know of there is an API in Android for that) or at least the BSSID of your current hotspot (there is an API for that AFAIK) and decide based on that where you are.

If there was a great solution to do that Google would have probably done that already (they have to a limited extend: http://googlemobile.blogspot.de/2011/11/go-indoors-with-google-maps-60-for.html)