# Is there a way of obtaining the longitude and latitude of Wi-Fi access points for triangulation purposes

Tags: java, eclipse, triangulation

I'm trying to obtain the longitude and latitude positions of existing access points within an indoor environment using Java (Eclipse). I understand that these are needed to complete the triangulation method. I have spoken to the IT team and they're unable to provide me with these readings. However I'm wondering if there's another way to do this?

Comment: Hmmmmm , to my knowledge this isn't possible . GPS uses triangulation

Comment: I don't think I will be able to complete my project then, this could be a serious problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to work with signal strength. You cannot determine lat. & long. with wifi. It appears that a few iPhone apps leverage triangulation of wifi.

But for outdoor triangulation , the default is GPS.

See this question - [Wifi Triangulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009703/wifi-triangulation)

[Specifically this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1010473/763029)

Comment: I have the signal strength related to the three access points so how do I calculate the position now?

Answer (score 0):

If you knew the locations of the access points to within the tolerances required for your application and had a good way to accurately measure the distance between the APs and you had a way to account for signal attenuation between your measurement device and the APs then you could do a little bit of math to solve for where you are.

Java certainly has the mathematical functions you'd need to calculate your location.  However, there's a ton of other variables that you would need to account for while triangulating your position from just WiFi access points.

Answer (score 0):

Wifi transmission range usually are in a radius, you have to discover available networks.

[image: wifi map]

You cannot know the exact point where are you, but you can know the area where you are.

If you add the lat & long of the access point, and know the reach of each access point, you can play with sin, cos & tan to accieve the aproximate position.